# Basic css styles(like border-bottom) are not affecting on dynamic created table

Tags: php, html, css, tcpdf

I'm reading a table data from MYSQL and writing it in html format to generate PDF (using TCPDF LIbrary) . but in resulting PDF only some of inline html CSS are affecting including(color,width.height) but other css like border-botttom(which I need the most) or all others ar being ignored by library.

```
$bookings_table_Result = mysql_query($bookings_table_query);
$tbl_header = '<table style=\"width:900px; border: 1px solid black; padding:0px;\">';
$tbl_footer = '</table>';
$tbl = '';

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($bookings_table_Result)){
    $checkin = $row["checkin"];
    $checkout = $row["checkout"];
    $nights = $row["nights"];
    $guest = $row["guest"];
    $country = $row["country"];
    $guestcount = $row["guestcount"];
    $amount = $row["amount"];

    $tbl .= '<tr >

            <td style="border-bottom: solid 1px Black; width: 80px;">'.$checkin.'</td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; width: 80px;">'.$checkout.'</td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; width: 20px;">'.$nights.'</td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; width: 200px;">'.$guest.'</td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; width: 150px;">'.$country.'</td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; width: 40px;">'.$guestcount.'</td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid red; width: 80px; color: blue;">'.$amount.'</td>
            </tr>';
     };
$tbl .= '</table>';

$pdf->writeHTML($tbl, true, false, true, false, '');
```

I Uploaded the picture of Result PDF

[image]

Comment: For one thing, you have double-quotes where single-quotes should be used. Compare yours to this one line I transformed `$tbl_header = "<table style=width: 900px; border-bottom:1pt solid black; border: 1px; cellspacing='0'>";` and `<td style='border: 1px solid #000000; width: 80px;'>'.$checkin.'</td>` (tested).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo error in the line you use `border-bottom` , see:

```
... '<table style="width: 900px; border-bottom:1pt solid black;" border: 1px; cellspacing="0">';
                        This is out of the style attribute!! ------^
```

Answer (score 0):

From the look of it, you are not generating a valid html table: You don't seem to add the table header to your `$tbl` variable.

If that is not the problem (you don't show where you output the table...), you'd better post the generated html instead of the php as this seems more related to `html` and `css` than `php`.

Answer (score -1):

when you echo a style in html using php try changing your code to something like this:

```
 $tbl .= '<tr >
        <td style=\"border: 1px solid #000000; width: 80px;\">'.$checkin.'</td>
        <td style=\"border: 1px solid #000000; width: 80px;\">'.$checkout.'</td>
        <td style=\"border: 1px solid #000000;  width: 20px;\">'.$nights.'</td>
        <td style=\"border: 1px solid #000000; width: 200px;\">'.$guest.'</td>
        <td style=\"border: 1px solid #000000; width: 150px;\">'.$country.'</td>
        <td style=\"border: 1px solid #000000; width: 40px;\">'.$guestcount.'</td>
        <td style=\"border: 1px solid #000000; width: 80px;\">'.$amount.'</td>
        </tr>';
```

when using single quote `''` you need need to include backslashes to tell the server to keep the `""` when echoing your table.

I had a similar problem when i was using php to echo my tables from mysql db.

jeroen makes a good point. You need to add the beginning table declaration if you want to create a valid html table.

You also seem to be styling the table outside of your style definition as well.

change

`$tbl_header = '<table style="width: 900px; border-bottom:1pt solid black;" border: 1px; cellspacing="0">';`

to

`$tbl_header = '<table style=\"width:900px; border-bottom:1px solid black; border: 1px solid black; padding:0px;\">`

However probably no point in the border on the bottom then one on the entire table because your last border declaration is going to override the previous one. . .

Comment: You are incorrect about needing to include backslashes to escape double-quotes within single-quotes. You only need them if using double-quotes within double-quotes or single-quotes within single quotes